# Find the locus of points $P$ such that the distances from $P$ to the sides of a given triangle can themselves form a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Find the locus of points $P$ within a given $\triangle ABC$ and such that the distances from $P$ to the sides of the given triangle can themselves be the sides of a certain triangle.

Join $PA,PB,PC$ and let the perpendiculars from $P$ meet $BC,CA,AB$ in $D,E,F$ respectively. Then, $$PA^2 = PE^2 + AE^2 = PF^2 + FA^2$$ $$PB^2 = PD^2 + BD^2 = PF^2 + BF^2$$ $$PC^2 = EC^2 + PE^2 = PD^2 + CD^2$$
$$\therefore PD = \sqrt{PC^2 - CD^2} = \sqrt{PB^2 - BD^2}$$ $$PE = \sqrt{PA^2 - AE^2} = \sqrt{PC^2 - CE^2}$$ $$PF = \sqrt{PB^2 - BF^2} = \sqrt{PA^2 - AF^2} $$
How do I proceed using this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the triangle is equilateral, then the sum of the distances from an arbitrary point inside the triangle to the three sides is equal to the height of the triangle, which is a constant. So the three perpendiculars are the lengths of a triangle when all of them are not longer than half the height of the given triangle. The point $P$ must lie inside the midpoint triangle of the given triangle.

For a triangle in general, I used Excel to generate random points and plot all points satisfying the condition.

[image]

[image]

My conclusion is that $P$ must be a point inside the incentral triangle of the given triangle.

We first consider the limiting case when the sum of the lengths of two perpendiculars is equal to that of the third one.

[image]

Let $BE$ be the bisector of $\angle ABC$ and $CF$ the bisector of $\angle ACB$, where $E$ lies on $AC$ and $F$ lies on $AB$. Let $G$ be a point on $EF$.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be the feet of perpendicular to $BC$ from $E$, $F$ and $G$ respectively. Let $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ be the feet of perpendicular to $AC$ from $F$ and $G$ respectively. Let $Z_1$ and $Z_3$ be the feet of perpendicular to $AB$ from $E$ and $G$ respectively.

Note that $EX_1=EZ_1$ and $FX_2=FY_2$.

We have $\displaystyle \frac{GX_3-EX_1}{FX_2-EX_1}=\frac{EG}{EF}$, $\displaystyle \frac{EZ_1-GZ_3}{EZ_1}=\frac{EG}{EF}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{GY_3}{FY_2}=\frac{EG}{EF}$.

Therefore,

$$\frac{GX_3-EX_1}{FX_2-EX_1}=\frac{EZ_1-GZ_3}{EZ_1}=\frac{GY_3}{FY_2}$$

$$\frac{GX_3-EX_1}{FX_2-EX_1}=\frac{EX_1-GZ_3}{EX_1}=\frac{GY_3}{FX_2}$$

So,

$$GX_3-EX_1=GY_3-(EX_1-GZ_3)$$

$$GX_3=GY_3+GZ_3$$

(Note: this equality holds also for external points of division of $EF$ if we consider negative lengths.)

If $P$ is a point inside $BCEF$, let $Q$ be a point on $EF$ such that $QP$ is perpendicular to $BC$. The distance from $P$ to $BC$ is less than the distance from $Q$ to $BC$. The distance from $P$ to $AC$ is greater than the distance from $Q$ to $AC$ and the distance from $P$ to $AB$ is greater than the distance from $Q$ to $AB$. We can now conclude that the distance from $P$ to $BC$ is less than the sum of the distance from $P$ to $AB$ and the distance from $P$ to $AC$.

Let $D$ be a point on $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$.

[image]

Repeating the above arguments, the perpendiculars from $P$ to the three sides of the triangle are the lengths of a triangle if and only if $P$ lies inside $\triangle DEF$.

Comment: One small question, in "$\frac{GX_3 - EX_1}{FX_2 - EX_1} = \frac{EG}{GF}$" shouldn't it be $\frac{EG}{EF}$ instead of $\frac{EG}{GF}$? In fact should'nt all $\frac{EG}{GF}$ be $\frac{EG}{EF}$ ?

Comment: @Helix Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The essential quantities are the distances $d_a$, $d_b$, $d_c$ of $P$ from the sides $a$, $b$, $c$ of the given triangle $\triangle$. We therefore should describe the problem in such a format that these quantities become simple, preferably linear, functions of the data.

Let the incircle $\kappa$ of $\triangle$ have radius $r$ and its center  at the origin $O$. Let 
$$r(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha),\quad r(\cos\beta,\sin\beta),\quad r(\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma)$$
be the  points of contact of $\kappa$ with the sides $a$, $b$, $c$ of $\triangle$. The distance $d_a$ of $P=(x,y)\in\triangle$ from the  side $a$ is then given by
$$d_a=r-(x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha)\ ,$$
and similarly for $d_b$ and $d_c$. The triangle inequality $d_a\leq d_b+d_c$ then leads to the condition
$$x(\cos\beta+\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha)+y(\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha)\leq r\ .$$
The boundary of the set of points fulfilling this condition is the  line $$\ell_a:\qquad x(\cos\beta+\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha)+y(\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha)= r\ ,\tag{1}$$ and we obtain two more such lines $\ell_b$, $\ell_c$. It follows that the feasible region (the "locus" in question) is a triangle $T$ containing obviously the point $O$. We now have to find the vertices $L_\iota$ of $T$. To this end I supplement $(1)$  with the equation for $\ell_b$:
$$x(\cos\gamma+\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)+y(\sin\gamma+\sin\alpha-\sin\beta)= r\ .\tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $x\cos\gamma+y\sin\gamma=r$. This says that the vertex $L_c:=\ell_a\wedge\ell_b$ is lying on $c$. Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ leads to
$$-x\sin{\alpha+\beta\over2}+y\cos{\alpha+\beta\over2}=0\ ,$$
which says that $L_c$ is lying on the angle bisector $C\vee O$ of $\triangle$.

I can leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For points $P$ inside the triangle the condition $d_A=d_B+d_C$ is a part of a line. Can you find two points on it?

So the region should be bounded by three lines.

Comment: Why do we have "For points $P$ inside the triangle the condition $d_A=d_B+d_C$ is a part of a line"? I noticed this fact with some experiment but do not have a simple explanation of this.

Comment: @CY Aries: recall the formula for the distance from a point to a line. On one side of the line the sign inside the absolute value has the same sign.

Comment: Do you mean the formula $\frac{Ax_1+By_1+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$? I can't see how to use it.

Comment: I know that the answer is the interior of the incentral triangle and this probelm is easy if the given triangle is equilateral. But the case for a triangle in general is not so trivial to me. Do we have to ffind the equations of the sides and do the complicated calculations?

Comment: @CY Aries: you only need to know that the place of equality is a segment. then you have two points on it so it's clear what it is.

Comment: I actually have a proof myself but I am not satisfied with it as I can't tell that the solution is the interior of a triangle in the first place without some experiments. I wiil post my proof and please comment on it and point what I am missing.

Comment: @CY Aries in the question it's mentioned that the locus, wherever it is, is inside the triangle

Answer (score 1):

Let PA’, PB’ and PC’ the perpendicular distances to the sides BC, CA and AB. WOLG, we can assume PA’ is the longest and PB’ the shortest among the three. For this to happen, P should be inside the region bounded by $\alpha$ (the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$), $\beta$ (the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$) and the line AC.

[image]

(1) Form the //gm PA’QB’; (2) Let the red circle (center = A’, radius = A’Q) cut AP at Q’; (3) Let the blue circle (center = P, radius = PC’) cut PA’ at D.

According to triangular inequality, we need $PC’ (= PD)$ $\gt PQ’$. The limiting case is when $PC’ = PQ’$ (i.e. when D and Q’ are coincide). For this reason, we draw the line $\lambda$, which is a line parallel to BC and at a distance of PA’ = PQ’ + Q’A.

The locus of P is therefore the purple region bounded by $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: That's not really true, you can get a point $Z$ just above $BC$ such that it's distances from the other side are same and hence a triangle can be formed.

Comment: @Helix My assumption is "PA' is the longest among the three distances". As mentioned, point Z, which is just above BC, does not qualify.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, is the locus pointed out only valid when $PA'$ is the longest?

Comment: The same logic equally applies when PB' (or PC') is the longest. But then we have to draw another (similar) picture which will show another feasible region for that scenario.